# iFraming a page with streaming video - video does not display

Tags: html, iframe, video-streaming, html5-video

I am trying to iframe a page containing a streaming video. The streaming video does not work when I view the iframe. It works fine when the original page is viewed directly in browser. What am I missing here? Is the stremaing video protected by some mechanism that does not let is display within the iframe?
Please also suggest any alternative solution to be able to display external streaming videos on my site.
Thanks!
The iframe code is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <BODY>
  <iframe src="http://aajtak.intoday.in/livetv.php" width='800px' height='1000px' />
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome 14 http://jsfiddle.net/ex937/

Comment: @Pekka - the video does not appear within the iframe. Please see this link for the screenshot http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/43/imgof.png/

Comment: I tried the link on jsfiddle and even there the video does not run. It just does not seem to start up. I am using chrome 14 as well.

Comment: Strange - the fiddle works for me. I may be wrong with my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, you are showing you are trying this from a `file://` URL.

I don't know *which* security shenanigans are involved (The browser's or Flash's), but I'm fairly sure it will go away if you use a `http://` URL instead.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ex937/)

Comment: I have put the html on my local Apache and it does not work. If you are able to see it working, then maybe the stream is locked by region. I am located in US. Are you in the same region? Thanks!

Comment: @Ashish I'm in Europe. But a regional block doesn't make sense if you can see it directly on http://aajtak.intoday.in/livetv.php as you say

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Cross Origin problem. Since you are using file://, it cannot play the video from 'http://' or 'https://'. If you can run your page in 'http://' or 'https://' at localhost, you will make it easy to work. In addition, if it does not work, you can set 'cross-origin' as 'anonymous'.